# difference when printing null pointer in linux and macos

Tags: c, linux, macos, compilation, clang

I'm having a problem with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *p = NULL;
    printf("%p\n", p);
    return (p);
}
```

It compiles normally (clang), but in one computer, a Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with clang version 12, this code prints (nil), while in another machine, a MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 with clang version 11, this code prints 0x0. Why is this happening? It has to do with the compiler version or os? Is there any way to make the MacOS print (nil) instead of 0x0?

Comment: The C specification doesn't specify the format of pointer output. It's up to the implementation of `printf` to print it in any way it want.

Comment: You could write your own formatter for pointers to handle NULL the way you want.

Comment: And to nitpick a little: First of all the `%p` format is for printing `void *` pointers only, and you need to cast it as such or you will have *undefined behavior* (because of mismatching format specifier and argument type). Secondly you declare `main` to return an `int`, then you return an `int *`. That's also wrong. You should return a small non-negative integer (where `0` is considered "success").

Answer (score 1):

The 2018 C standard specifies, in clause 7.21.6.1, paragraph 8, that for a `p` conversion:

> … The value of the pointer is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an implementation-defined manner.

Presumably, the C implementation you used on Ubuntu defines the manner of conversion to produce the printing characters “(nil)” for a null pointer, and the C implementation you used on macOS defines it to produce “0x0”. (A C implementation includes the compiler and the libraries used, along with other tools, and the formatting for pointers is likely a function of the standard library implementation you linked in, rather than the compiler or the operating system *per se*. Specific documentation of the conversion may be lacking or hard to find, in spite of it being required by the C standard.)

> Is there any way to make the MacOS print (nil) instead of 0x0?

Use `if (p) printf("%p\n", (void *) p); else printf("(nil)\n");`.